# Upgrading Authorize.net Webservice Reference(api) to Akamai (api2)

Tags: c#, asp.net, authorize.net, web-reference, akamai

I am Trying to Set debug URL and live URL based on flag for service call to authorize.net like below..

```
if (isDebug)
{
    API_URL = "https://apitest.authorize.net/soap/v1/Service.asmx";
}
else
{
    API_URL = "https://api.authorize.net/soap/v1/Service.asmx";
}
```

And then for old api webreference (https://api.authorize.net/soap/v1/Service.asmx) i was able to set this API_URL for webservice call using their **service** class like below where **CustomerProfileWS** is namespace of web reference

```
public CustomerProfileWS.Service Service
{
    get
    {
        if (service == null)
        {
            service = new CustomerProfileWS.Service();
            service.Url = API_URL;
        }
        return service;
    }
}
```

Now same way I tried to use new Akamai URL (https://api2.authorize.net/soap/v1/Service.asmx) as webreference with namespace as **CustomerProfileWS2** but I am not able to find CustomerProfileWS2.Service to set API_URL.

How can i set **test** URL or **Live** URL with new api2 webreference?

Any help on this will highly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have your Akamai Staging environment setup correctly?  You should have the ability to hit your origin directly, and you should also be able to hit Akamai Staging, as well as Akamai production.  If any of these is configured incorrectly, you can experience unexpected results.  Lots of times it has to do with SSL mismatches, so you may need to use host file entries or configure other workarounds when testing your origin or Akamai Staging environment.